# Connection of Event hubs to Azure Databricks

Tags: python, azure, azure-databricks

I want to add libraries in Azure Databricks for connecting to Event Hubs. I will be writing notebooks in python. So which library should I add for connecting to Event Hubs?

As per my search till now I got a spark connecting library in Maven coordinates. But I don't think I will be able to import it in python.

Answer (score 0):

Structured streaming integration for Azure Event Hubs is ultimately run on the JVM, so you'll need to import the libraries from the Maven coordinate below:

```
 groupId = com.microsoft.azure
  artifactId = azure-eventhubs-spark_2.11
  version = 2.3.10
```

**Note:** For Python applications, you need to add this above library and its dependencies when deploying your application.

For more details, refer "[Structured streaming + Event Hubs Integration Guide for PySpark](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-spark/blob/master/docs/PySpark/structured-streaming-pyspark.md#deploying)" and "[Attach libraries to Spark Cluster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-databricks/databricks-stream-from-eventhubs#attach-libraries-to-spark-cluster)".

And also, you may refer [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49365852/how-to-process-eventhub-stream-with-pyspark-and-custom-python-function/52770596#52770596) thread, which addresses a similar issue.

Hope this helps.